# customising the path planning algorithm

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, jackal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to change the path planning algorithm which is used for the robots to find the shortest path to reach the goal in rviz. i want to customize it with my algorithm so as to find the shortest path efficiently . so, i want to know which package is responsible for path planning of robots.[NOTE: I am currently working on simulated jackal robot.]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232082/customising-the-path-planning-algorithm/) by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Path/trajectory planning is performed using the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) which itself consist mainly of the [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) node and a (local/global) [costmap](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d).
*move_base* loads a local and a global planner plugin.
So what you want is probably to load your selfmade global planner here.

You can refer to the Tutorial [Writing a Global Path Planner as Plugin for ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS).

There are also a lot of other questions here regarding your concerns:

- [Question 1](http://answers.ros.org/question/39119/custom-global-planner/)
- [Question 2](http://answers.ros.org/question/152196/about-a-way-to-change-default-global-planner/)
- [Question 3](http://answers.ros.org/question/231959/writing-a-global-path-planner-as-plugin-in-ros-in-hector-quadrotor/)
- ...

I recommend to first investigate how the navigation stack works in general before trying to implement your own plugin interface.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajith kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26236/ajith-kumar/) on 2016-04-21**:
thank you sir for your reply.